# Modify char* in GDB while debugging

Tags: debugging, arm, gdb, remote-debugging, cpu-registers

While I debug with GDB I can print string:

```
x/s $r0
```

The output is

```
IDog123456
```

I want to change the value so when I print x/s $r0 I will see

```
ICat45555
```

I have tried to :

```
set $r0+1 ={int} 0x43617434 #Cat4
set $r0+5 ={int} 0x35353535 #5555
```

But it doesn't work , How can I do that without malloc ? only with hex string please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the gdb expression parser operates similar to the current language, so, in the above, when you write:

```
set $r0+1 ={int} 0x43617434 #Cat4
```

The left hand side is an integer constant, which can't be assigned to.

Instead, you should write this as you would in C:

```
set *($r0+1) = (int) 0x43617434
```

Which should do the job.

Sometime, you might end up needing to cast the pointer of the LHS too, like this:

```
set *((int *) ($r0+1)) = (int) 0x43617434
```

But I suspect in your case you'll be OK.